# Chrome extension go above a flash element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I make the extension above a flash element like on YouTube. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

See screenshot of bug:
http://twitpic.com/3egnxk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to put something above flash is to set `wmode` embed parameter to `opaque` or `transparent`. You can't dynamically set it, flash object needs to be recreated:

```
$("embed").attr("wmode", "opaque").wrap("<div>");
```

You can run this right away on page load so user wouldn't notice.

The other disadvantage is that flash in this mode loses focus (you won't be able to play a flash game with keyboard for example).

Comment: Great, that works perfect! Now instead of just showing up above the flash element - do you know how to put the chrome object above in focus? When I try this it still is active in the background object when selecting above a flash element like a YouTube video.